# Django rerun signal as created

Tags: django

I've a signal running when some model *DiseaseCase* is saved:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=DiseaseCase)
def add_or_edit_map_feature(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    ...
    if created:
        do_something()
```

If I update some fields of one Instance of *DiseaseCase* Model using Django Shell or Django Admin `do_something()`  will of course not run as the instance is edited but not created.

Let's say I do not want to update the signals code, but still rerun do_something(). How would I override the created boolean for the signal to be true using Django shell?

Comment: why don't just simply remove `if created` statement, if you want `do_something()` to be applied to all saved instances?

Comment: I've edited my question. My intention is to not update the code, but still rerun do_something() for a debugging case. So I'm looking for a way to just set created to true by use of django shell

Comment: But I guess what should work is just to set the id to none and save it again. Doing so should set created to true ...

Answer (score 0):

You can us `else` or `if not created`

```
 @receiver(post_save, sender=DiseaseCase)
    def add_or_edit_map_feature(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        ...
        if created: #this signals will be triggered when created any object 
            do_something()
        else: #add your logic for do somethings
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer the question. I do not want to update the code but set created to true on save.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just creating a duplicate record. Which works fine in my case.

```
from d_database.models import DiseaseCase

instances = DiseaseCase.objects.all()
for instance in instances:
    instance.id = None
    instance.save()
```